# How do I format printing a double value with a space after "+"

Tags: java, formatting

I use:

```
"%+.1f"
```

And get:

```
+6.0
+2.5
-2.2
```

But need:

```
+ 6.0
+ 2.5
- 2.2
```

Is this possible using the standard java Formatter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, and there's no mention of it I could see in [the Formatter docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), but you can always use something like:

```
public static String formattedFloat(float f) {
    return String.format("%s %.1f", f >= 0 ? "+" : "-", Math.abs(f));
}

// Example
System.out.println(formattedFloat(-2.21234f);
// prints "- 2.2"
System.out.println(formattedFloat(6f);
// prints "+ 6.0"
```

Comment: I do this like you. I think there's a simpliest way.

Answer (score 0):

The sign is simple a flag set on/off, not distinct part of the output. `System.out.format(..)` uses [java.util.Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) and I don't see any option to 
change that in the same function call. You're best bet is to get the output
in a string and format it manually.